# Add delay within cloud page using Ampscript / SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

Is it possible to add delay within cloud page using Ampscript / SSJS?

What I'm trying to accomplish is, create a record in Sales Cloud from the cloud page, wait for 5 seconds, then query the same record. It will have a status updated and based on the status display different sections in my cloud page.

Comment: Did you resolve this? When I try to use setTimeout() I only get a 500 page.

Answer (score 2):

I think if I was approaching this and had to wait a period of time I would:

1. create the record in sales cloud and I would have the page load,
   with just a loading indicator on the front end
2. set a setTimeout() redirect to another or the same page that then
   queried the previously created record
3. Render the dynamic content.